# c# check textbox autocomplete is empty

Tags: c#, .net, autocomplete

The [AutoCompleteSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource(v=vs.110).aspx) and [AutoCompleteMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx) properties of the TextBox allow me to use automatic completion in textboxes.

I have bound directly a datatable as AutoCompleteSource of the textbox and it works well.

In some situations that the input words is not available in the sources, the auto completion has no result and so, i need to do something else in those situations.

How should i check whether the automatic completion result is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach you can take. The following code will get suggestions in the `TextChanged` event of the textbox when more than 3 characters have been entered. We go get the suggestions and then check if any suggestions were returned. If yes, we set the `AutoCompleteCustomSource`. Otherwise, we will do something--whatever we want to do.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
    if (t != null)
    {
        // Here I am making the assumption we will get suggestions after
        // 3 characters are entered
        if (t.Text.Length >= 3)
        {
            // This will get the suggestions from some place like db, 
            // table etc.
            string[] arr = GetSuggestions(t.Text);

            if (arr.Length == 0) {// do whatever you want to}
            else 
            {
                var collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                collection.AddRange(arr);

                this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
            }
        }
    }
}
```